# Flutter library asserts/errors not shown fully in log on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm currently using Flutter 2.8.0. Printing into logs is still fine, but for some reasons, long error logs are shortened with ... and stacktrace are not shown. I already enable the showing structured error/stacktrace option in settings.
For example:
[image]

Comment: add your code used to log in console

Comment: Whats the code you are using

Comment: I don't think that should matter but for this example I set clipBehavior of a container to Clip.hardEdge without adding decoration property